# Program exits when assigning var = 0.0;

Tags: c, linux, gcc, simulink, exit

I am testing a program autocoded by Simulink Coder in C, using the real time target option. This tool outputs a series of header and source files based on the Simulink model design. Since I'm only testing at the moment, the model is just a sum of two signals.
In one of the source files are the functions which are of interest: model_initialize, model_step and model_terminate. The purpose of obtaining these functions is that they are implemented in an RTEMS (Real-Time Executive for Multiprocessor Systems) operating system. For that, a manually coded .c file containing the RTEMS code is cross compiled  (I'm using Eclipse IDE for Linux), generating an executable which I can run on Linux using a simulator tool. That RTEMS .c file will contain the function calls `model_initialize()`,etc.

Now the problem: When, in the middle of the program, I call `model_initialize`, the program behaves oddly. (I remind you that these functions were autocoded, I only coded the "puts" lines.)
Inside the `model_initialize()` function I have:

```
  puts("Inside Init");
  rt_InitInfAndNaN(sizeof(real_T));
  ...
```

The program prints the line **Inside init** so I know it works up to that point, however, when the 2nd line is ran, the program simply exits (sucessfully it says), disregarding everything that follows. (I know so because I used the gdb debugger)
In an attempt to get to the bottom of this, I stepped into this function, which was defined in another source file and showed:

```
void rt_InitInfAndNaN(size_t realSize)
{
  (void) (realSize);
  rtNaN = rtGetNaN();
  rtNaNF = rtGetNaNF();
  rtInf = rtGetInf();
  rtInfF = rtGetInfF();
  rtMinusInf = rtGetMinusInf();
  rtMinusInfF = rtGetMinusInfF();
}
```

Again using GDB it showed me that the line that makes the program exits is  `rtNaN = rtGetNaN();` I again stepped into this function.

```
real_T rtGetNaN(void)
{
  size_t bitsPerReal = sizeof(real_T) * (NumBitsPerChar);
  real_T nan = 0.0;
  if (bitsPerReal == 32U) {
    nan = rtGetNaNF();
   ...
```

Which showed that the line that effectively makes the program exit is `real_T nan = 0.0;`
`real_T` is just a data type defined by the Simulink code as:

```
#ifndef REAL_T
# ifdef REAL64_T
#  define REAL_T real64_T
# else
#  ifdef REAL32_T
#   define REAL_T real32_T
#  endif
# endif
#endif
#ifdef REAL_T
 typedef REAL_T real_T;
#endif
```

with `REAL64_T` coming from:

```
#ifndef REAL64_T
# ifndef __MWERKS__
#  if DBL_MANT_DIG >= 52
#   define REAL64_T double
#  endif
# else
#  define REAL64_T double
# endif
#endif
#ifdef REAL64_T
 typedef REAL64_T real64_T;
#endif
```

Which is Simulink's way of very redundantly saying `real_T` is of type double I think.

So why on Earth would the program exit when assigning 0.0 to a variable of type double? I was even afraid that nan was a restricted name and I tried changing it but it still exits. I can't comment out this line to see what would happen since it is integral to the whole program. I've also tried separating the assignment as

```
real_T nan;
nan = 0.0;
```

But it didn't work either. Does anybody have any idea why such an assignment would cause the program to exit (successfully apparently) and not execute the lines in front? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @4386427 Well I think  typedef REAL_T real_T says that real_T is of type REAL_T and earlier in "define REAL_T real64_T" I think it says REAL_T is the same as real64_T and then in "#  define REAL64_T double" it says that REAL_64 is of type double. If I'm missing something please let me know. Aditionally, I have used breakpoints instead of your suggested prints, so I'm pretty sure that if I did that, it would print the before one but not the after.

Comment: Well actually I mispoke because I didn't undertsand your suggestion completely. I did this: puts("before realt nan");
  real_T nan;
  puts("after realt nan");
  nan = 0.0; And both prints get printed but when nan = 0.0 the program exits

Comment: I don't know...If I dig deeper I find no assignment to DBL_MANT_DIG so that might be something to look at. But does assigning a 0.0 to an undefined type reason enough for the program to exit? Shouldn't there be an error?

Comment: I commented out the DBL_MANT_DIG >= 52 condition and the error persists

Comment: I hadn't but as I expected when I do that it doesnt get printed becuase the program exits at the nan = 0.0 line

Comment: I made a rather revealing finding. The error appears to have nothing to do with this function in particular. If, in my "main" program, I use float a; a = 2.1; It exits at the second of those lines. What could this be related to? It works with int. I assume something to do with the compiler? Oh and the message I get at gdb is [Inferior 1 (Remote target) exited normally]

Comment: Num  -1 / Desc - Remote Target / Executable - *it's empty*

Comment: It's during, I can't type anything after the crash.

Comment: I figured it out! I'm terribly sorry I kind of wasted your time....I was under the impression the problem would be with the code itself since I didn't recognize the program exitting as a compiler fault but rather a code fault. Again I apologize, the compiler had to be set to support floating point. Thanks for trying to help anyway!

Comment: Comments cleaned up

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This problem is only related to the RTEMS compiler. **It has to be set to support floating point.** I was unaware that assigning floats to variable without that option would cause the program to exit and not output an error message, as a result I was expecting it to be code-related. Thanks to those who took the time to read this.
To set the RTEMS compiler to support floating point, the option `-msoft-float` must be inserted after the compile command line.
In Eclipse this is set in Project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cross GCC Compiler -> Miscellaneous.

Comment: @4386427 sure, will do